# OpenIdConnect Correlation Cookie not found when user click link from Office application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ms-office, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an app that is authenticating with Azure Active Directory using OpenIdConnect. Everything is working fine except when I link to my site from a Office Application (excel/ word). From these applications I get a "Exception: Correlation failed.".

From my research it seems to be that office is first doing the 302 redirect and then opening that page not the original link.

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1252

After a recommendation for how to handle this scenario. I don't want to have to make to many changes to the authentication flow and introduce bugs.

I have tried redirecting to a different page on my site when a user-agent of excel is detected. I thought then the correct cookie would be set and I could redirect from there to the requested page which would then trigger authorization. No luck though

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
{                   
     if (context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString().Contains("Microsoft Office Excel"))
     {

              string redirect = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + "/Home/Office" + "?url=" + context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase + context.Request.Path;
              context.Response.Clear();
              context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
              context.HandleResponse();
              return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement a decent solution using owin middleware. Largely with the help of this post: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/78

I how ever did need to convert it to .net core 2.0. Here's the converted code:

```
public class MsOfficeLinkPrefetchMiddleware 
{
    RequestDelegate _next;

    public MsOfficeLinkPrefetchMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (Is(context, HttpMethod.Get, HttpMethod.Head) && IsMsOffice(context))
        {
            // Mitigate by preempting auth challenges to MS Office apps' preflight requests and
            // let the real browser start at the original URL and handle all redirects and cookies.

            // Success response indicates to Office that the link is OK.
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            context.Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
            context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
            context.Response.Headers["Expires"] = "0";
        }
        else if (_next != null)
        {
            return _next.Invoke(context);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private static bool Is(HttpContext context, params HttpMethod[] methods)
    {
        var requestMethod = context.Request.Method;
        return methods.Any(method => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(requestMethod, method.Method));
    }

    private static readonly Regex _msOfficeUserAgent = new Regex(
        @"(^Microsoft Office\b)|([\(;]\s*ms-office\s*[;\)])",
        RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private static bool IsMsOffice(HttpContext context)
    {
        var headers = context.Request.Headers;

        var userAgent = headers["User-Agent"];

        return _msOfficeUserAgent.IsMatch(userAgent)
            || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headers["X-Office-Major-Version"]);
    }
}
```

Startup

```
app.UseMiddleware<MsOfficeLinkPrefetchMiddleware>();
```

Hope this is able to help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks Tim! This works great. +1 Just make sure you add the `app.UseMiddleware<MsOfficeLinkPrefetchMiddleware>();` early on in the pipeline so the request doesn't get intercepted prior to reaching this piece of middleware.

Answer (score 1):

In Startup.ConfigureServices(), you'll need to add this line

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for 
        //non -essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```